# get a update from a running process in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

**Update 2/14** -- Is there anybody that has an idea on how to help me with this?

I have a file import process that takes anywhere from a few seconds to a full minute to complete.

I need to provide an update to the user on what is going on.
I am a 'converted' WinForms programmer who is still working on a transition to this 'web thing' as it seems to be getting traction.

How do I do this?  Normally I would update an onscreen control or counter.
If this is a long answer I don't need a detailed code response.  Links to good examples or tutorials will work also.

I am making the call to the controller by an ajax post:

```
 // Make your POST
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ReadAndSaveCSVData", "Home")',
            data: fdata,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    if (response) {
                        alert("Data Imported");
                        $('#fUpload').val('');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Import Failed");
                    }
                }
                //load1.style.display = 'none';
            },
            error: function (e) {
                //load1.style.display = 'none';
                //alert(e.responseText);
            }
        });
```

The controller that is doing the work is setup like this:

```
  using (LOBContext db = new LOBContext())
                    {
                        using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                LOBContext db2 = new LOBContext(); //create a seperate data context for creating new records that need to be accessed here.

                                foreach (var li in list)
                                {
                                    PayrollTimecardEntries tc = new PayrollTimecardEntries();

                                    //Get the Id's of the related records, or create them
                                    getPayrollDeptType(db, db2, li, tc);
                                    getEmployeeId(db, db2, li, tc);
                                    getPunchTypeId(db, db2, li, tc);

                                    tc.PunchDate = li.punchDate;
                                    tc.Hours = li.hours;
                                    tc.PaycorCreatedDatetime = li.paycoreCreatedDatetime;
                                    tc.CreatedbyPaycorUsername = li.paycoreCreatedByUserName.Trim('"');

                                    //see if this is a new entry or not
                                    int result = (from seek in db2.PayrollTimecardEntries
                                                  where seek.EmployeeId == tc.EmployeeId &&
                                                  seek.Hours == tc.Hours &&
                                                  seek.PaycorCreatedDatetime == tc.PaycorCreatedDatetime
                                                  select seek.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (result == 0) //only add new timecard entries
                                    {
                                        db2.PayrollTimecardEntries.Add(tc);
                                        db2.SaveChanges();

                                    }
                                }
                                transaction.Commit();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                transaction.Rollback();
                                throw ex;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    importSuccess = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return importSuccess;
```